# Возможно ли написать динамически вложенные if блоки?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача сортировать пользователей по дате последнего входа в систему.

Я использовал метод `sort` с moment.js для решения этой задачи. Первое моё решение было такое.

```
 myArray.sort((a ,b ) => {
     return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "seconds") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "seconds");
 });
```

Он не сработал.Проблема как я думаю было в том что разница между датами было очень большое, а конкретно в месяцах.А я хотел взять разницу в секундах и сравнить.

Потом я решил эту задачу таким образом.Проблема в том что код получился ужасным.

```
    myArray.sort((a ,b ) => {
      if ( moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "months") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "months") === 0 ) {
        if ( moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "days") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "days") === 0 ) {
          if ( moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "hours") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "hours") === 0  ) {
            if ( moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "minutes") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "minutes") === 0  ) {
              if ( moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "seconds") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "seconds") === 0  ) {
                return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "seconds") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "seconds");
              }
            } else {
              return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "minutes") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "minutes");
            }
          } else {
            return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "hours") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "hours");
          }
        } else {
          return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "days") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "days");
        }
      } else {
        return moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, "months") - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, "months")
      }
    });
```

Этот код работает следующим образом.Если месяцы равны, он сравнивает по дням если дни равны, то по часам и т.д.

Вопрос в том как написать это более лаконично может  как то динамически написать блоки `if`, но как не знаю.

Comment: а что мешает перевести даты в timestamp и сортировать по ним?

Comment: @Zhihar Будет тоже самое разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумней было бы сделать примерно так:

```
 myArray.sort((a ,b ) => {
     return new Date(a.lastLoginAt) - new Date(b.lastLoginAt);
 });
```

где a.lastLoginAt, b.lastLoginAt - это что-то пригодное для конструктора Date.

Answer (score 2):

как ответил Zhihar timestamp решит проблему и не надо будет столько накручивать НО столько одинаковых строк? почему? не лучше ли обернуть в одну единственную функцию и вызвать ее например так

```
const isLarge = (a,b,str) => {
  return  moment().diff(a.lastLoginAt, `${str}`) - moment().diff(b.lastLoginAt, `${str}`) === 0
}
```

и потом вo всех if

```
if(isLarge(a,b,"months"))
```

это не ответ к вопросу а лишь попытка улучшения понимания возможностей JS

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (+1)